# Saving image to file

Tags: c#, winforms, image, gdi+, save

I am working on a basic drawing application. I want the user to be able to save the contents of the image.

[image]

I thought I should use

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsState img = drawRegion.CreateGraphics().Save();
```

but this does not help me for saving to file.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could try to save the image using this approach

```
SaveFileDialog dialog=new SaveFileDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
   int width = Convert.ToInt32(drawImage.Width); 
   int height = Convert.ToInt32(drawImage.Height); 
   using(Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height))
   {
       drawImage.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
       bmp.Save(dialog.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   }
}
```

Comment: where would this image be saved?

Comment: Any place indicated by the property dialog.Filename

Comment: What is "drawImage"? I tried the Bitmap but it doesn't recognize DrawToBitmap()

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628992/how-to-use-control-drawtobitmap-to-render-a-form-into-a-bitmap-without-its-decor It is a method of the Form instance currently containing the drawing area

Answer (score 56):

You can try with this code

```
Image.Save("myfile.png", ImageFormat.Png)
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx

Comment: Note: Not static, you have to use `objectName.Save()`

Answer (score 5):

If you are drawing on the Graphics of the Control than you should do something draw on the Bitmap everything you are drawing on the canvas, but have in mind that Bitmap needs to be the exact size of the control you are drawing on:

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myControl.ClientRectangle.Width,myControl.ClientRectangle.Height);
  Graphics gBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
  gBmp.DrawEverything(); //this is your code for drawing
  gBmp.Dispose();
  bmp.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Or you can use a `DrawToBitmap` method of the Control. Something like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myControl.ClientRectangle.Width, myControl.ClientRectangle.Height);
myControl.DrawToBitmap(bmp,new Rectangle(0,0,bmp.Width,bmp.Height));
bmp.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save image , save the file in your current directory application and move the file to any directory .

```
 Bitmap btm = new Bitmap(image.width,image.height);
    Image img = btm;
                        img.Save(@"img_" + x + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        FileInfo img__ = new FileInfo(@"img_" + x + ".jpg");
                        img__.MoveTo("myVideo\\img_" + x + ".jpg");
```