# how can i save generated image tomy folder?

Tags: c#, image, save

i have the following code to generate my bitmap image using C#. i just want to know how i can save the output image to my desktop directory instead of showing to my picture box?

```
        Image bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
          Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
          g.DrawString(randomString, myFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(0, 0));
          pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: how are g and bmp related?   You might glean something here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909905/saving-image-to-file

Comment: only that? no more syntax and where doeas it save the image?

Comment: @CowBoy Just type `Image.Save` to google and go the first msdn link. It also contains an example. Is this so hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `pictureBox1.Image.Save("your path", ImageFormat.your_format);`

You will need this reference: `using System.Drawing.Imaging;`

Comment: when you write `ImageFormat.` intelliSense should give you suggestions, for example `ImageFormat.Jpeg`

Comment: do i need to add any reference? and what can i put to save it for example on my desktop (general address that works for all computer)

Comment: @CowBoy answered that in an edit. Add: `using System.Drawing.Imaging;`

Comment: i got it cool! but it doeasnt save it, i put "C:\Users\M.R.B\Desktop" but its giving me error

Comment: @CowBoy what is the error? Maybe the problem lays in "\" Try this instead `@ "C:\Users\M.R.B\Desktop\File name"`. "\" is used in Escape Sequences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: its working, just one thing, do you know why its drawing a black square? while i was Expecting to have my character font to be black not the back ground!!!

Comment: @CowBoy Probably that is the default bitmap color. Try this `g.Clear(Color.White)` before writing text.