# Save image from camera (live image)

Tags: c#, image, camera

For my final project in school ( even though I'm not a programmer ) I have to make a program that reads barcodes. I have to use Common Vision Blox.

I got a live feedback from the camera and I'm able to snap it. 
But I want to save this picture now, I tried using this method ([Saving image to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909905/saving-image-to-file)), but there seems to be a fault. Probably because I don't actually know which reference to use. I'll add my program in pictures.

[image: Pic 2: Code part 1]
[image: Pic 3: Code part 2]

I would like to save the snap in JPEG or something, so that I call it further in the program to start the barcode recognition.

Hope you guys can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should always copy and paste code into the question instead of posting images. Code can be formatted as codeblocks so it gets highlighted aswell. This makes it possible for people to copy and modify the code to write an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually quite simple: The object `axCVimage1` has a method `Save()` and a method `SaveImageByDialog()`. Use whatever method suits your needs. For saving the current image to a jpg file, simply provide a file name that has the extension 'jpg'. If you need control over the compression ratio and quality, use the the method `SaveLossyImage()` instead.