# I want to load the images dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, loadimage

I want to dynamically bind some images in my folder.

For example. When you click the button, file1.jpg on pictureslibrary is displayed in the first cell of the gridview.
If you click the button again, File 2 will be displayed in the second cell.

I want to display the image when the button is clicked like this.

I think the best way to find one is the gridview. 
I want to dynamically save the image to a specific folder and show it each time I click the button.

But The existing methods I have looked at are adding existing images to the gridview as resources, assets, etc.

So I wonder how I can load dynamically stored images into gridview in this way.

Do you have any suggestions for doing this? or is it impossible way?

Comment: What kind of dynamic storage are you using?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Sorry I can't understand that the kind of dynamic storage. I just want to save jpg image file using BitmapImage.

Comment: @Kay Check out these links for saving image : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161359/save-bitmapimage-to-file  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909905/saving-image-to-file

Comment: @AnoopJ I saw what you sent, but it's a bit different than the storage I used. Because I saved ink data to jpg file. Anyway I used BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId`.

Comment: Please show more what you have done.